# Codifying ways to think and write about imprecise ideas?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy, foundations

This question will not be about affine spaces; rather those are mentioned here as one of many examples.

- A vector space has an underlying set and a field of scalars and an operation of linear combination, satisfying certain axioms.  Given scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ and vectors $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$, one gets a vector $c_1\vec{v}_1+\cdots+c_n\vec{v}_n$.
- An affine space has an underlying set and and a field of scalars and an operation of affine combination, satisfying certain axioms.  Given scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ satisfying $c_1+\cdots+c_n=1$ and points $\mathbf{p}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{p}_n$, one gets a point $c_1\mathbf{p}_1+\cdots+c_n\mathbf{p}_n$.
- If one chooses any point at all --- call it $\mathbf{0}$ --- in an affine space, it becomes a vector space with that as the zero point if if one defines the linear combination $c_1\mathbf{p}_1+\cdots+c_n\mathbf{p}_n$, with $c_1+\cdots+c_n$ not necessarily equal to $1$, to be the affine combination
  $$
  c_1\mathbf{p}_1 + \cdots + c_n\mathbf{p}_n + (1-c_1-\cdots-c_n)\mathbf{0}.
  $$
- **But** one can also define an affine space by saying it has an underlying set $A$ of points and a vector space $V$ that acts transitively on $A$.

So someone who reads the second definition of "affine space" thinks an affine space has more structure than a vector space, because when you discard $A$ and keep $V$, you've got a vector space, but when you have both, you have an affine space.  But someone who reads the first definition thinks an affine space has less structure than a vector space because you have to choose one point to be the zero point, and that's additional structure.

Now it seems to me that the idea of an affine space as a vector space that has forgotten its origin conveys the idea more clearly and directly than the $(A,V)$ characterization does.

So a way of making an idea precise may illuminate or obscure the initially imprecise idea that was to be made precise.

That means that there actually is an idea to be made precise, that exists independently of the ways of making it precise that are then developed afterwards.

Has anyone every tried to codify good ways of thinking about those independent imprecise ideas, as they have with precise reasoning in mathematics?  Or would that put one in danger of making them precise and thereby causing them to cease to be the independent imprecise ideas that were one's topic?

Comment: That's funny, I just had a conversation about the topic of affine & vector spaces with a friend. The (soft) conclusion, which seems to match your thesis, was that properly formalizing the ideas is a lot of work for something that is relatively straightforward. Furthermore, the simple idea gets lost in translation.

Comment: At the risk of "missing the point entirely", I'm not convinced that an affine space in the first sense (affine combinations) gives rise to an affine space in the second sense (free transitive action; you don't mention free, but I tend to think this was an accidental omission.) How does one obtain - canonically - a free transitive action of a vector space on a set, given that we're only given an affine space in the first sense?

Comment: @goblin : My third bullet point explains how to get a vector space.  Once you've got that, you got the free transitive action: given a vector $\vec x$, just add that vector to every point to get its image under the action. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I think you're right. That is, indeed, a canonical way of constructing a free and transitive action of a vector space on an affine combination space, because the vector $\vec{x}$ we choose is (in some sense) irrelevant; we get the same vectorspace/action pair "up to isomorphism" of the vector space and its action. Its VERY subtle though. For example, if we have an affine map $f : A \rightarrow B$, I reckon its impossible to lift this (in a canonical way) to a linear transformation  between the corresponding vector spaces.

Comment: @goblin : I actually suspect I'll be sure of what you mean if I digest it carefully enough, but I'm not sure.  Maybe more explicitness from you could make it clear. In particular, do you intend your affine map $f:A\to B$ to be a map from just any "affine-combination space" to any other? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, look, its possible the last sentence of my previous comment was wrong. Yes, I meant that $f$ is an arbitrary affine-combination preserving function between arbitrary affine-combination spaces. I might get back to you later, if I can get my head around what is tripping me up here.

Comment: Let me try to get this idea out. If $X$ is a set, we get a pointed set $X^*$ by adjoining a new element $*$. This is functorial; it defines the point-adjunction functor $F:\mathbf{Set} \rightarrow */\mathbf{Set},$ where $*/\mathbf{Set}$ is the category of pointed sets and point-preserving functions.

Comment: Here's the crazy thing though; if $X$ is a non-empty set, another way of obtaining a pointed set is to simply choose a point of $X$ arbitrarily, and then distinguish it. Since the resulting pointed set is independent - up to isomorphism - of the point we chose to distinguish, I guess this is a well-defined construction; we get a **function** $f : \mathbf{Set}_{\neq \emptyset} \rightarrow */\mathbf{Set}$. Its not functorial though, AFAIK; there's just no sensible way of taking a function between non-empty sets $X \rightarrow Y$ and obtaining a point-preserving function $f(X) \rightarrow f(Y)$.

Comment: Philosophically, we might say "$f$ isn't functorial because we had to make an arbitrary choice to build $f(X)$ from $X$." Now consider *your* construction. Given an affine combination space $X$, you show how to build a vector space/action pair $g(X).$ You do this by choosing an arbitrary point of $X$, and arguing that the choice of point doesn't matter. This gives a function $g : \mathbf{Aff}_{1} \rightarrow \mathbf{Aff}_{2}$, where $\mathbf{Aff}_1$ is the category of affine combination spaces and affine-combination preserving functions...

Comment: ... and $\mathbf{Aff}_2$ is the category of ordered triples $(a,V,A)$, where $V$ is a vector space, $A$ is a set, and $a$ is a free transitive action of $V$ on $A$. The arrows in this case are pairs; an arrow $(a,V,A) \rightarrow (a',V',A')$ would consist of a linear transformation $\varphi : V \rightarrow V'$ and a function $j : A \rightarrow A',$ subject to the constraint that $j(v+a) = \varphi(v)+j(a)$, for all $v \in V$ and $a \in A$. My question, really, and the main point of my confusion, is: can we make $g$ into a functor in a sensible way?